# Object is possibly 'null' - getting this error while using onchange event in angular 11/12

Tags: angular

I am getting an error in my project where I am using angular 11, in app.component.html when using onchange event ($event.target.checked). Here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div *ngFor="let Car of Cars">
      <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(Car.id, $event.target.checked)"> {{Car.email}}<br>
  </div>

<button (click)="duplicate()" >Get values </button> 

{{emailFormArray | json}}
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  emailFormArray: Array<any> = [];
  Cars :any
  ngOnInit() {
this.Cars = [
  { email: 'email1', id: 1 },
  { email: 'email2', id: 2 },
  { email: 'email3', id: 3 },
  { email: 'email4', id: 4 }
];
  }
  onChange(email: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    if (isChecked) {
      this.emailFormArray.push(email);
    } else {
      let index = this.emailFormArray.indexOf(email);
      this.emailFormArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  duplicate() {
    console.log(this.emailFormArray);
  }
}
```

Comment: In which line is the error

Answer (score 0):

Create appropriate labels for the checkbox fields and also use the `id` of the checkbox item as a `for` attribute in label

Remember `id` should be unique.

On `change` event - use forloop | foreach | forin loops to iterate it over and check whether checked using Jquery or JS DOM